# How to subset with empty characters in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

This one has me tearing my hair out. Suppose I have a data frame like this:

```
xx <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3), B = c(4,5,6))
rownames(xx) <- c("p", "q", "r")
```

This gives:

```
  A B
p 1 4
q 2 5
r 3 6
```

I have R code that can result in an empty character (character(0)) that is used to try and subset df xx. If I define a zero character:

```
z = character(0)
```

and then I subset xx with:

```
subset(xx, rownames(xx) != z)
```

I get:

```
[1] A B
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

but what I want is the full array, xx, since there is no empty row name. To make this work I have to convert the empty character to and empty string:

```
z <- ""
```

Using z <- "", when I subset I get the entire df back, which is what I expect. Explicitly trapping and converting all of these empty characters to empty strings is too clumsy. How to solve this??

Comment: The empty character shows up from some computations earlier in the code. Normally, I will be subsetting with the characters representing row names, but sometimes the code delivers an empty character as the subsetting name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `%in%` instead of `!=`:

```
subset(xx, !(rownames(xx) %in% z))
```

Comment: Perfect! Works with both the empty character and the empty string. Thanks!!